# Is there a lexicon for the icons on a Mac?

Tags: macos

I want to know about the "lightning bolt" symbol and wondering if there is a lexicon or summary of the meanings of all these icons.

Comment: Are you referring to thunderbolt icon on hardware? Can you edit a picture or upload a screen image? I’ll refine my answer if needed. https://www.apple.com/thunderbolt/

Comment: Or if you want to jump down a rabbit hole https://www.folklore.org/. Stories by the people who invented the Mac, with some time spent on the *original* iconography of the Mac

Answer (score 1):

Apple Publishes a style guide that covers official naming:

- https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewBook?id=1161855204

Older versions were PDF so you can find them online, but it’s now an electronic publication.